# PHP - Codeception: Actions don't focus fields

Tags: php, selenium, codeception

I'm trying to execute an acceptance test with Codeception and Selenium, but it looks like the fillField() method does not focus the input field. Which is necessary because when the element loses it's focus I need to send an ajax request. I used the code below:

```
$I->fillField('.js-project.tt-input', $this->project);
```

Manually triggering the focus with the following code, does not work either:

```
$I->executeJS('$(".js-project.tt-input").trigger("focus");');
```

The javascript code that needs to be executed for the ajax request:

```
$('.js-project.tt-input').blur(function() { ... }).trigger('blur');
```

Anyone an idea, about why it would do this?

Comment: The code is triggered on the loss of focus and your test is only triggering the gain of focus. Focus another field to simulate the loss of focus.

Comment: @FlorentB. Tried it and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$I->appendField('.js-project.tt-input', $this->project);` it focuses the element and fills out at the same time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).